# Edit the template of admin top page

Tags: python, django

I am editing the template of admins

I successfully override the each model's edit page.

`/myapp/template/admin/modelA/change_list_results`
`/myapp/template/admin/modelB/change_list_results`

However how can I override the top of admin??

After login, there is a application and table lists.

I tried to override these below from /django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/ folder

`/myapp/template/admin/app_index`
`/myapp/template/admin/index`
`/myapp/template/admin/base`

However , still in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override base_site.html and include base.html using extends. I use this method to override branding.

tempaltes/admin/base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block branding %}
    <h1 id="site-name">
        Name of the site
    </h1>
{% endblock %}
```